# What is the default baud rate without calling Serial.begin?

Tags: serial

I cannot find the answer from [official document](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/begin/) and also surprised no one asked the same question.

What is the default baud rates if I didn't call `Serial.begin`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no default baud rate. When the sketch starts, the serial port
is disabled (thus non-functional). Calling `Serial.begin()` enables the
port.

Comment: Really appreciate! I just found even though I use `Serial.println` in `loop` function. The TX LED light won't blink unless I added `Serial.begin` in `setup` function.

Comment: Just for completeness: On some alternative boards that are also compatible with Arduino IDE (like e.g. ESP8266 and ESP32 boards), some information is transmitted on serial before your sketch even starts. The default baud rate then is dependent on the chip and/or board.